# Scala: provide class type in parameter

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have one method that takes class as parameter like below.

```
    val hBaseRDD = spark.sparkContext.newAPIHadoopFile(path,
      classOf[org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat[ImmutableBytesWritable, Result]],
      classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable],
      classOf[Result], conf)
```

I want to write a method that takes parameter as Type of class and than I can call this line inside it. like below.

```
case class SequenceInput(conf: Configuration,
                         path: String,
                         storageClass: String,
                         keyClass: String,
                         valueClass: String,
                      ){
  override def read(sparkSession: SparkSession): DataFrame = {
    val rdd = sparkSession.sparkContext.newAPIHadoopFile(path,
      classOf[storageClass],
      classOf[keyClass],
      classOf[valueClass], conf)
    rdd
  }
```

but this ask me to create storaClass, keyClass, valueClass but these are the variable that holds the class type.

How to do this?

Comment: Change `classOf[xxx]` with just `xxx`

Answer (score 0):

You're writing a constructor, not a method, but change

```
storageClass: String,
keyClass: String,
valueClass: String
```

To be Class objects, not Strings

Then your function can

```
return sparkSession.sparkContext.newAPIHadoopFile(path,
      storageClass,
      keyClass
      valueClass, conf)
```

Then

```
val storageClass = Class.forName(config.get("storage_class"))
...
// remove path from the constructor since you should be able to use multiple paths 
val df = SequenceInput(storageClass,...).read(spark, path)
```

Keep in mind that, `Class.forName` expects the fully qualified name, not just `"ImmutableBytesWritable"`, for example

Comment: this method has to be called from read method and also in case class input parameters I cannot change from String because It will be taken from config file ans has to be string

Comment: So? All I did here was extract the `classOf` call outside of the class. Doesn't really matter how you get the class... Last I checked, `classOf[]` type argument cannot be a string, though, so what do you plan on doing there?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to convert a `String` into `Class`. You can do this with `Class.forName(String)`

```
case class SequenceInput(conf: Configuration,
                         path: String,
                         storageClass: String,
                         keyClass: String,
                         valueClass: String,
                        ) {
  override def read(sparkSession: SparkSession): DataFrame = {
    val rdd = sparkSession.sparkContext.newAPIHadoopFile(path,
      Class.forName(storageClass),
      Class.forName(keyClass),
      Class.forName(valueClass), conf)
    rdd
  }
}
```